# Reason/Bucklescript + bs-jest: How to compile files with a *.test.re pattern outside of __tests__ folder?

Tags: jestjs, reason, bucklescript, bs-jest

***Background:***

I am currently using bs-jest for unit testing. In addition, I am using the bsb init project, meaning that I am first compiling files using Reason/Bucklescript + then running compiled files using Webpack.

Jest by default will pick up files that have the word test in them, for instance component.test.js, will be picked up by default by Jest.

Bs-jest will work by default, with files being put in the  `__tests__` directory. However, my spec files following the `*.test.re` pattern, put in my components folder, i.e. put in a folder other than `__tests__` will not compile to the appropriate `*test.js` file.

***Objective:***

Compile:

```
├── Components
|   ├── toolbar
|   |   └── toolbar.re
|   |   └── toolbar.test.re
```

To:

```
├── Components
|   ├── toolbar
|   |   └── toolbar.bs.js
|   |   └── toolbar.test.bs.js
```

and then have Jest run and work as it currently does by default.

Any help is more than appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that in your bsconfig.json, your package is marked as dev. Which means it will not be able to be picked up in non dev sources, such as your src folder. By moving it to a regular dependency, it will work as expected.

That being said, now you can understand architecture of perhaps why it is in it's own folder, due to compilation reasons.

Comment: If by that you mean bs-jest, you do not want to have jest as a non-dev dependency. Your application does not require jest to run and thus it should never be a runtime dependency.

Answer (score 2):

I've used bs-jest in two projects where the tests were not held in a root level `__tests__` directory, as I prefer to use `src/test`. You need to tweak the way jest runs in order to run the tests and collect coverage. Typically, you just need to add `--env=jsdom` and specify the directory, for example:

`"test": "jest --env=jsdom --testMatch='**/test/*test.{js, re}' --watch"`

[Example package.json](https://github.com/RawToast/bouken/blob/master/package.json) and [another example](https://github.com/RawToast/dokusho/blob/master/dokusho/package.json)

Answer (score 0):

you can customize the testfiles paths in `package.json`, e.g.:

```
  ...

  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "watch:test": "jest --watchAll",
  },

  ...

  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testMatch": [
      "**/tests_jest/*.{js,re}",
      "**/tests_jest_blablabla/*.{js,re}"
    ]
  }
```